# How to set up Spring multi maven module using spring boot

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I would like to evolve my Spring application with a better architecture. The technologies I'm using are : spring portfolio ( spring mvc, spring test, spring Web, spring core, spring rest...) 
Today I'm using packaging to structure the different layers of my application: models, services, api and of course web where I have my controllers.

I would like to know how can I use the power of spring boot to make a multi module maven architecture with an xml spring configuration for a Web application. I read that spring boot have an embedded tomcat and since I'm using eclipse with a separate tomcat server I would like to deploy my application on it and I think that this can create a problem.

I already found some links on github with this type of projects most of them are not elaboring an architecture of a Web application and use a class for spring configuration with the embedded tomcat that spring boot offers.

Thank you

Ps: sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by multi module. If you want to build your jar for multiple environment you can use maven profile for it. Spring boot is nothing but a spring project which ease the configurations for you.

Regarding deployment to your own server, you have to convert the jar to war. Read "What about the Java EE Application Server" section of below link.

https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications